# Correct future tense of flying

Tags: verbs, ambiguity, future-tense

[image: The Question]

By ear I feel that the answer is "I'm going to fly", but the more I think about it and the more I see "will fly" to Paris as a legitimate option as well, can you guys help me out decide with some explanation?

Comment: Technically, they're all wrong. The answer should be either "Yes, I have" or "No, I haven't". If you look past that, the question is really after the location, not the mode of transport. And if you're prepared to peel *that* layer off, well ... all the options are grammatical, except the last.

Comment: I agree with Lawrence on all 3 points.It looks like you have to select just one alternative, so it looks like a badly written question.

Comment: Do not just post a graphic. It cannot be interpreted by screen readers. Type the actual text into the question itself.

Comment: @Lawrence The last option is not ungrammatical. It's the descriptive future. It's often used when people are looking at a map and planning actions, describing what people will do in the future, but in the present tense: *"First, you go over here, then you open that, then …"* As such, all four tenses could be correct.

Comment: @JasonBassford In isolation, it's a grammatical sentence. But as a reply to the given question, if it's not ungrammatical, it's a non sequitur.

Comment: @Lawrence  I disagree. I've used it in just this way myself, and heard it used by others. It's conversational and quite idiomatic. In fact, I'd almost argue that "I fly to Paris" is ***more*** common than "I will fly to Paris" or "I am going to fly to Paris." The only part of any of the answers that's unusual is *fly* itself. Normally, we'd just answer "Paris" or "I'm going to Paris," and not mention flying in the first place.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oddly enough, "Have you decided where to go?" "I fly to Paris on Monday." sounds okay to me. I'll leave it to others to comment on how it sounds without "on Monday".

Comment: @Lawrence Interesting. I don't personally find "I fly to Paris on Monday" significantly different than "I fly to Paris," but I do understand how it could sound like a more *complete* statement, which might have something to do with the shorter version sounding odd because of a lack of expected information.

Comment: It's a very poorly conceived question. Your uncertainty about which choice to make should not cause you to worry about your fluency in English.

Comment: Choice depends on whether there are other travel options: both how to get there and where you could fly to. Also, how soon it is - tomorrow or next year. IMO "I fly to Paris" or "I will fly to Paris" puts more emphasis on the choice than "I'm going to fly to Paris", but when spoken it depends on tone: "I *fly* to Paris" or "I fly to *Paris*".

Answer (score 0):

Basically with the "going to" we are refering to something we have already decided, in the other hand with "will" we are refering to a prediction or a future choice that we are making in that exact moment.

In general first comes "will" and then "going to".
Since the description reads: "You have made all your holiday arrangements", it means we already decided what to do, so the optimal choice would be "am going to fly"